# Share lucene analyzer between Solr Cloud schema.xml and Lucene Monitor

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am attempting to configure an instance of Lucene Monitor (https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_6_0/monitor/index.html). The Monitor api requires that you provide an Analyzer instance. I already have a separate Apache Solr Cloud setup with a schema.xml configuration file in zookeeper, and would like to reuse the configurations from that schema.xml file for a specific solr field.

Are there any best practice for how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I did it by creating a spring api service which uses solrj client from solr-core  package to connect to zookeeper and download configuration to local dir.
After that monitor service uses this configuration to create Indexschema object and query parser.
You can get lucene Document object from DocumentBuilder.toDocument(SolrInputDocument doc, IndexSchema schema) and pass it to monitor.

Similarly while registering queries, query object can be created using analyzer returned by indexschema.